# Is there a way to disable notes/files in results set for Generic Inq?

Tags: acumatica

I'm working through some poor performance when exporting data (StockItems) from Acumatica using a generic inquiry. The issue I'm having is that Acumatica is going after every item in the result set and then getting the notes for each item.

Is there a way to disable this for generic inquiry screens? I don't need notes, I just want the data. My main query finishes in .02 seconds but then there is another 2-3 seconds of SQL time while it gets the notes.

Comment: Do you have the code? Otherwise this question is off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 1):

If you use DACs made from SQL Views the results grid doesn't add the notes. But once you join a DAC that is note enabled they start to populate in the results grid.

Comment: That's the way I ended up going. Some of the data I needed it was also more efficient to do a sub query join to group and sum data instead of joining the table and letting Acumatica do the grouping.